# How can I use range condition inside HAVING statement in SPARK SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

dataframe's name is WikipediaTable.

I want to create a table with the following conditions:

project='en' row

Values ​​in the size field greater than or equal to 1000 and less than 10000

sorted by title in descending order

#code

```
df = ss.createDataFrame(columns, ['project', 'title', 'count', 'size'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("WikipediaTable")

selected = ss.sql("SELECT project, title, size FROM WikipediaTable \
WHERE project = 'en' \
ORDER BY title DESC")
selected.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxls.png)

Here, it is completed by limiting the value of size between 1000 and 10000,
but I am not sure how to make it using the HAVING statement.
How to use && or AND condition here?

```
selected = ss.sql("SELECT project, title, size FROM WikipediaTable \
WHERE project = 'en' \
# HAVING size >=1000 & size<10000**I guessed this, but failed.**
ORDER BY title DESC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having is working on aggregates so you can use it only with group by which is missing in your case

If you dont want to group records just use where which is working on records level

In your case it may look like this

```
WHERE project = 'en' \
AND size >=1000 AND size<10000
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your current query missed Group by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-having.html#:%7E:text=The%20HAVING%20clause%20is%20used,with%20a%20GROUP%20BY%20clause.) and a wrong AND operator

As per official documentation above :

> The `HAVING clause` is used to filter the results produced by GROUP BY
> based on the specified condition. It is often used in conjunction with
> a GROUP BY clause.

The query can be written as :

```
selected = ss.sql("SELECT project, title, size FROM WikipediaTable \
WHERE project = 'en' \
GROUP BY project, title, size \
HAVING size >=1000 AND size<10000 \
ORDER BY title DESC")
```

You can even write is using [between operator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#between) as below :

```
selected = ss.sql("SELECT project, title, size FROM WikipediaTable \
WHERE project = 'en' \
GROUP BY project, title, size \
HAVING size BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 \
ORDER BY title DESC")
```